# Передача массива с индексами из одной функции в другую

Tags: c++, c, массивы, функции

У меня есть программа из 3х файлов, которая получает на вход матрицу (максимум 10x10). Мне необходимо вычислить максимльное значение по модулю и его индекс. С первым проблем не возникло, но застрял со вторым. Никак не получается передать массив с индексами (max_i) в функцию вывода (print_summa).

```
//main.cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Matrix.h"

int main(void)
{
    double matrix[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
    double summa[MAXCOL];
    int n, m;
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("m=");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    input_matrix(matrix, n, m);
    summa_in_col(matrix, n, m, summa);
    print_matrix(matrix, n, m);
    print_summa(summa, m);
    return 0;
}

//Matrix.h
#define MAXROW 10
#define MAXCOL 10
void input_matrix(double mat[][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol);
void print_matrix(const double mat[][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol);
void summa_in_col(const double mat[][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol, double* ar);
void print_summa(const double* ar, int n);

//Matrix.cpp
#include"Matrix.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include "math.h"

void input_matrix(double mat[][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol)
{
    int r, c;
    for(r = 0; r < mrow; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < mcol; c++)
        {
            printf("  mat[%d][%d]=", r, c);
            scanf("%lf", &mat[r][c]);
        }
    }
}

/* Вывод на экран исходной матрицы              */
void print_matrix(const double mat[][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol)
{
    int r, c;
    for(r = 0; r < mrow; r++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(c = 0; c < mcol; c++)
        {
            printf("%6.1f", mat[r][c]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* Функция, вычисляющая максимальный по модулю элемент в столбце*/
void summa_in_col(const double mat[][MAXCOL], int mrow,
                  int mcol, double* ar, int* max_i)
{
    int i=0, r, c, ind = 0;
    double max;
    max = mat[0][0];
    for(c = 0; c < mcol; c++)
    {
        for(r = 0; r < mrow; r++)
        {
            if (abs(max) < abs(mat[r][c]))
            {
                max = mat[r][c];
                ind = c;
            }
        }
        ar[c] = max;
        max_i[i] = ind;
        i++;
    }
}

/* Функция, выводящая на экран вектор решений, полученный в
   результате обработки матрицы
*/
void print_summa(const double* ar, int n, const int* max_i)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Max of column %d:%6.1f\tIndex:%d\n", i+1, ar[i], max_i[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Распишите подробнее назначение переменных, а то по наименованию нифига не понятно

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "math.h"

#define MAXROW 10
#define MAXCOL 10

void input_matrix(double mat[MAXROW][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < mrow; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < mcol; ++c)
        {
            printf("mat[%d][%d] = ", r, c);
            scanf("%lf", &mat[r][c]);
        }
    }
}

/* Вывод на экран исходной матрицы              */
void print_matrix(const double mat[MAXROW][MAXCOL], int mrow, int mcol)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < mrow; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < mcol; ++c)
            printf("%6.1f", mat[r][c]);
        
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

/* Функция, вычисляющая максимальный по модулю элемент в столбце*/
void summa_in_col(const double mat[MAXROW][MAXCOL], int mrow,
                  int mcol, double* ar, int* max_i)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < mcol; ++c)
    {
        double max = abs(mat[0][c]);
        unsigned max_index = 0;
        for(int r = 0; r < mrow; ++r)
        {
            double abs_val = abs(mat[r][c]);
            if (max < abs_val)
            {
                max = abs_val;
                max_index = r;
            }
        }
        ar[c] = max;
        max_i[c] = max_index;
    }
}

/* Функция, выводящая на экран вектор решений, полученный в
   результате обработки матрицы
*/
void print_summa(const double* ar, int n, const int* max_i)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("Max of column %d: %6.1f\tIndex: %d\n", i+1, ar[i], max_i[i]);
}


int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int m;
    printf("m = ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    double matrix[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
    input_matrix(matrix, n, m);

    int max_indexes[MAXCOL];
    double summa[MAXCOL];
    summa_in_col(matrix, n, m, summa, max_indexes);
    
    print_matrix(matrix, n, m);

    print_summa(summa, m, max_indexes);
    
    return 0;
}
```